# Kivy togglebutton only turning sound on/off once

Tags: python, kivy, togglebutton

Ive tried looking for an answer to this without much luck.

Im trying to build an application in kivy that starts and stops a sound as the button is toggled. The sound does what I want the first time the button is toggled, but the second time the button only starts the sound, but does not stop the sound.

Here is my code so far.

'''code'''

```
class MainApp(App):

def build(self):
    layout = BoxLayout(padding=10)
    self.oceanButton = ToggleButton(text='Ocean',
    background_normal='C:/Users/micha/Desktop/Code/Soothing Sounds/picture/oceanpic.jpg')
    self.oceanButton.bind(on_press=self.on_press_button)
    layout.add_widget(self.oceanButton)

    return layout


def on_press_button(self, *args):
    waveSound = SoundLoader.load(
         'C:/Users/micha/Desktop/Code/Soothing Sounds/sounds/ocean.wav'
        )
    
    if self.oceanButton.state == 'down':
        waveSound.play()
        waveSound.loop = True
        print('On')
    else:
        waveSound.stop()
        print('Off')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `on_press_button()` method always creates a new instance of `Sound` (using `SoundLoader`). So, when the `ToggleButton` state is not `down`, it calls the `stop()` method on that new instance, and the `Sound` that was created on the previous call continues to play.

You can fix that by keeping a reference to the created `Sound` instance, and using that instance to call `stop()`:

```
def on_press_button(self, *args):
    if self.oceanButton.state == 'down':
        self.waveSound = SoundLoader.load(
             'C:/Users/micha/Desktop/Code/Soothing Sounds/sounds/ocean.wav'
            )
        self.waveSound.play()
        self.waveSound.loop = True
        print('On')
    else:
        self.waveSound.stop()
        print('Off')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, John! That helped and definitely clarified what the issue was for me!